# Adaptive subdivisions on a large mesh

Tags: subdivision-surface

If you are trying to do large landscape with adaptive subdivisions, and you've just got one huge plane for the landscape, will blender subdivide it more closer to you or is the same number of subdivisions applied to the entire mesh?

Wondering if I can get the same effect faster by just splitting the plane into multiple objects all with adaptive subdiv turned on, or some other methods are preferred.

Answer (score 4):

It will subdivide it more when it's closer to you.

If you're at all concerned about how adaptive subdivision is going to subdivide a face, you can give a face a wireframe material and render it.  The wireframe material will communicate the actual subdivision used:

[image]